# How to handle play framework exceptions due to cache downtime (redis)

Tags: caching, playframework, redis

I'd like to use a redis cache for content caching in my play server (play version 2.3.9, scala version 2.11)

I have a play action that i'm wrapping with the Cached action as outlined in the Play Framework documentation [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaCache#Caching-HTTP-responses), i.e.

```
 def action(input: String) = Cached.status(_ => "cachekey", 200, 43200) {
    Action {implicit request =>
...
```

The play plugin for redis works great. However i realized I'm introducing a new point of failure into my system.

If the redis server becomes unavailable or goes down, the action will throw a hard exception.  I would like this to instead behave like a cache miss and still gracefully return the response to the user without caching.

I tried to wrap the cached call in a try/catch block:

```
    def safeCache(key: String, ttl: Int)(f: => Result)(implicit app: Application) = {
    try {
      Cached.status(_ => key, 200, ttl) {
        Action { implicit request =>
          f
        }
      }
    } catch {
      case e: Throwable =>
        Logger.error(s"Could not retrieve cache key for $key due to ${e.getMessage}", e)
        NewRelic.noticeError(e)
        Action { implicit request =>
          f
        }
    }
   }
```

But the exception is actually thrown from an iteratee outside my application's control, so the

```
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:42) ~[jedis-2.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.sedis.Pool.withJedisClient(sedis.scala:101) ~[sedis_2.11-1.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.typesafe.plugin.RedisPlugin$$anon$1.set_(RedisPlugin.scala:144) ~[play-plugins-redis_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.typesafe.plugin.RedisPlugin$$anon$1.set(RedisPlugin.scala:103) ~[play-plugins-redis_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at play.api.cache.Cache$.set(Cache.scala:61) ~[play-cache_2.11-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at play.api.cache.Cache$.set(Cache.scala:72) ~[play-cache_2.11-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at play.api.cache.Cached$$anonfun$play$api$cache$Cached$$handleResult$1.apply(Cached.scala:83) ~[play-cache_2.11-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at play.api.cache.Cached$$anonfun$play$api$cache$Cached$$handleResult$1.apply(Cached.scala:73) ~[play-cache_2.11-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at scala.PartialFunction$AndThen.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:190) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at play.api.cache.Cached.play$api$cache$Cached$$handleResult(Cached.scala:88) ~[play-cache_2.11-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at play.api.cache.Cached$$anonfun$build$1$$anonfun$apply$6$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(Cached.scala:57) ~[play-cache_2.11-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at play.api.cache.Cached$$anonfun$build$1$$anonfun$apply$6$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(Cached.scala:57) ~[play-cache_2.11-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:471) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:471) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:495) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:495) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
```

Is there a recommended pattern for incorporating this kind of redis caching into a play framework server while gracefully handling potential downtime with the new dependency?

Comment: Are you getting this error when the cache first starts? This process might be tied to the startup of your application (possibly via some lazy eval on play.api.cache.Cached). If so you might need to override how your application bootstraps.

Comment: FYI: line 61 in Cache.scala is `private val cacheApiCache = Application.instanceCache[CacheApi]` so it does appear to be related to initial cache start.

Comment: Ah I think you're right. I think this will need to be a much lower level fix than I thought. I think I'll just change my approach and use redis directly without the play response layer caching.